# Include jade in html

Tags: jquery, html, dom, pug

I would like to include a jade script inside an html element (to display like if it was part of the html) like this:

```
container.getElement().html('<include src="main.jade"</include>');
```

But obviously the include tag doesn't work. What should I use? (I can use jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile Jade into HTML rather than using some kind of inclusion from the DOM:

```
var jade = require('jade');

// Compile a function
var fn = jade.compile('string of jade', options);

// Render the function
var html = fn(locals);
// => '<string>of jade</string>'
```

Then you can compile that HTML into something, like an [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

```
var compiledElement = $compile('<string>of jade</string>')(scope);
someDomElement.append(compiledElement);
```

You can create a mock scope using `$rootScope.$new()`, or by getting a scope (or isolateScope) from an element using `element.scope()`, where element is some angular element.

Check out the [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/api/) docs.

Comment: What if I don't want to use angularjs?

Comment: Oh gotcha, I updated my answer. Yes, you could use `ng-include`, or it's equivalent $`templateCache` to do the include. But if you aren't using a library, you could just fetch the template using AJAX and then compile it using Jade.

Comment: Client-side does not have access your `main.jade` file, you would need an XMLHttpRequest to fetch it.

Comment: I get it but what I want is call the jade file from the client-side and the server will compile it automatically. I tried $(container.getElement()).load('main.jade') without success. I thought there would be an include tag where I can add a jade source...

Comment: Then you should be able to use `ng-include` directly, but note that ng-include takes an *expression*, so your path needs to be wrapped in quotes like this: `<ng-include src="'foo.html'"></ng-include>`. If you compiled your Jade templates into HTML on the server-side, and they're available on the client end as assets given a path, then that path should work for ng-include also.